# how to synchronize a method in java without affecting speed

Tags: java

I have a java application that is client server based. The server handles all the request from the client and respond back. I have created a method to query customer account on the server which is fine but some time the server returns account information that is not related to the account that the client has requested. After a few search i found that it could be threading issues so i decided to add synchronized key word on the method which solved that issue but my problem is that the application has slowed down, here is my code.

```
public synchronized List<String> queryCustomer(int AccountNumber) {
    List<String> acntinfor = new ArrayList();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pmst = null;
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    try {
        pmst = conn.prepareStatement("Select name,balance from tblaccount where Ac_number=?");
        pmst.setInt(1, AccountNumber);
        rs = pmst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            acntinfor.add(rs.getString("name"));
            acntinfor.add(rs.getString("balance"));
        }
        rs.close();
        pmst.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return acntinfor;
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    // db is class that has connection to my db
    DB b = DB.getDB();
    return b.getConnetion();
}
```

How can I improve the speed of the application?

Comment: How did it "slow down"? Is it running at a frame rate, and it's taking a lot more time per frame? Are specific actions taking longer to complete, as if it were waiting on something? Please be more specific

Comment: Does your `DB` class cache connections? If not, you should definitely look into it, maybe using a connection pool.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how putting synchronized helped you solve your problem of `some time the server returns account information that is not related to the account that the client has requested`?

Comment: What makes you think it needs speeding up? Modern day JVMs handle managing synchronization very efficiently.

Comment: It may be bacause of `caches connections` as suggested by icza. Try to close the connection `conn.close()`.

Comment: @Naman when the client send a query request without the synchronized the server responds quickly but at times give the wrong account to the user. But when i add synchronized key word the response takes longer

Comment: I have no doubt about your program because it is behaving as expected. But according to my knowledge, when client sends request, servlet container initializes a thread to serve it. And that thread will call queryCustomer method. If I am not wrong, there is no `static objects` which are getting changed by other threads as well. So the response will be given to that thread only i.e. query response. So I am getting confused how response is getting changed?

Comment: @NamanGala I am using java Nio for client/server communication

Comment: I don't have idea about java Nio. I would suggest to have look at the architecture of java Nio. And I strongly believe it will be same as servlet container(serving each request with new tread). If it is same, then I would suggest to take look at the answer(in comment) given by @icza.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronization creates a memory barrier and enforces a happens-before relationship to ensure data consistency. All this happens at the cost of performance. Synchronization should be used to have consistent data. If your application needs it, then you should use it.

What you can do is reduce the critical section. i.e, synchronize only that part of the code which might cause problems.

Note : Since java 6 update 23, *Escape Analysis* was introduced to find out sections of code where synchronization was being used unnecessarily (and a lot of other things). So, the JVM might just *optimize* your code (if the reference doesn't escape / if multiple threads don't access a synchronized block, then the monitor will not be locked..)